# Passing Edittext to a Thread

Tags: android

I am trying to pass a String value of EditText to a method in a thread, the method "channel.basicpublish". I have tried a number of ways in the method "basicpublish" like Edittext.gettext().tostring or declare global variables (above override) and passing them to local variables, but on the other hand I get an empty string though there is no error. I also tried bundle/intent, but nothing is working for me (gives error). The following code will be working because I am passing a plain string (Message="HelloRabbitmq"). So how I can pass a string from edittext to "basicpublish" which is in a thread?

```
public class HandlerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView tv;
    EditText etv;
    String QUEUE_NAME="bye";
    String EXCHANGE_NAME="logs";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);
        etv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.out2);
        etv.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                  // Perform action on key press
                  Toast.makeText(HandlerActivity.this, etv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   String  Kamran = etv.getText().toString();     
                   return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
     final Handler handler=new Handler();
     final Runnable r=new Runnable()
     {
            public void run() 
            {
                tv.append("Hello");

            }
     };
     handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
     Thread thread = new Thread()
     {
            @Override
            public void run() {             
                try {
                    while(true) {
                        sleep(1000);
                        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
                        factory.setHost("192.168.2.3");
                        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
                        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
                        channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout", true);
                        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
                       String message = "Hello Rabbitmq";                   
                        channel.basicPublish( "logs",QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
                        channel.close();
                        connection.close();
                        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
                        }
                }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }         
            }
     };
     thread.start();
             }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class variable should work fine for this...

I also made a few changes but feel free to change it back to how you had it, but there seemed to also be some other flaws in the code besides the text from the EditText view.

Something like:

```
public class HandlerActivity extends Activity {

private TextView tv;
private EditText etv;

private String QUEUE_NAME = "bye";
private String EXCHANGE_NAME = "logs";
private String message = "";

private Handler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    handler = new Handler();

    tv =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);
    etv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.out2);
    etv.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                Toast.makeText(HandlerActivity.this, etv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                message = etv.getText().toString();

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    handler.postDelayed(publish, 1000);

}

private Runnable publish = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            //You should probably not have this as "true", you should always have some way to bail out of this.
            //Technically even if you kill this activity it may never stop.
            while(true) {
                ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
                factory.setHost("192.168.2.3");
                Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
                Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
                channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout", true);
                channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);                 
                channel.basicPublish("logs", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
                channel.close();
                connection.close();

                //Why are you running the this loop again? Uncomment if thats REALLY what you want
                //handler.postDelayed(publish, 1000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my emulator doesn't respond to this code. But the class variable did the job, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set a **TextWatcher** on *etv* and to set a String member variable, let's say *etvValue*, to the value of *etv* in the **afterTextChanged** callback? Then, passing *etvValue* to basicPublish may work...

Comment: No, I havent but a declaring the gloabl variable like String string="", does the job. Anyways thank alot.